# encodeURIComponent and mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysql-real-escape-string, encodeuricomponent

I would like to ask you if it's necessary to use a `mysql_real_escape_string()` PHP function for data that I send into my DB in PHP ajax file if the data is encoded in my JS file using `encodeURIComponent()` function? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `encodeURIComponent` encodes the characters so they aren't misinterpreted in the URL (in transport via HTTP); `mysql_real_escape_string` escapes the string so that it isn't misinterpreted in the MySQL query (inside the database).

In other words, each has a completely different function; not to mention that you have *zero* guarantee that the request at your PHP file is actually coming from your AJAX call.